# Performing a Join on Three tables

Tags: sql, join

I want to perform a join on three tables.

**Table 1:** part_master

**Column:** Item, Item_status

**Table 2:** Order_Details

**Column:** Item, order_num, order_type

**Table 3:** Order

**Column:** order_num, order_type

**Here is the cardinality:**

part_master <--> order_details (1..1)

order <--> order_details (1..n)

I want to perform a search on order table, to retrieve item_status from part_master. In other word, I want to see item_status, for an order, using order_num as a search criteria.

I tries something like this, however, it throws a exception:

**select part_master.item_status from part_master where item = (select item from order_details where order_details.order_num = order.order_num)**

The error says, the second 'select' statement returns multiple results which is not correct..

Help....!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to see item_status which is in part_master table, using order_num from order table as a search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If an order contains more than one order detail row, your inner select

```
select item from order_details where order_details.order_num = order.order_num
```

will return more than one row.  Try it and see.

Changing your query to

```
select part_master.item, part_master.item_status from part_master where item in 
    (select item from order_details 
     where order_details.order_num = order.order_num)
```

should return what you want.